# mysqldump table selected row cron job

Tags: mysql, cron

I am using cron job to dump a table in my database. This code works fine and dumps me a sql file.

```
mysqldump pabu1v2_pabu tbl_students > /home/pabu1v2/autobackup/backups1.sql
```

I don't know how to dump only specific rows from this table. But do I wrote this

```
mysqldump pabu1v2_pabu tbl_students where="schoolid = '113'" > /home/pabu1v2/autobackup/backups1.sql
```

It gives me a blank sql.

Please, help. I am writing this directly in cron jobs not in php.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bsh
$ mysqldump pabu1v2_pabu tbl_students --where="schoolid = 113" > /home/pabu1v2/autobackup/backups1.sql
```

See [5.5.4 mysqldump — A Database Backup Program :: where](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where).